# Can we distinguish between gravity and electrostatic forces interacting on celestial bodies?

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, mass, charge, astrophysics

The orbit of one celestial body around another is thought to be caused by gravity alone. However, could part of the force determining the orbit (at least in theory) be caused by a difference in the electrical potential between the two bodies?
For instance we assume that Earth is electrically neutral. But do we have a way to exclude that there could be a surplus of electrons in Earth?

Comment: A large enough surplus of electrons would explode outward from the electrostatic repulsive force. Gravity alone would not be strong enough to keep that excess charge on Earth for long.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86529/2451

Comment: Agree. I am not considering a large surplus. One would in principle already do it

Comment: A "small surplus" would be insufficient to significantly affect orbits. The scales are such that you get significant neutralizing effects long before enough charge accumulates to overwhelm the long-range gravitational forces.

Answer (score 26):

> But do we have a way to exclude that there could be a surplus of electrons in Earth?

Yes.

First, the solar wind consists of many charged particles. If the Earth had a net charge then opposite-charges particles would be attracted and like-charged particles would be repelled. This would lead, on average, to an accumulation of opposite-charged particles until the Earth became neutral.

Second, there is no way for the Coulomb force to mimic the gravitational force in the solar system. If you have two objects interacting gravitationally then the force is attractive. If two objects interact electrostatically then the force is only attractive if one is positively charged and the other is negative. Now, add a third object to each: in the gravitational case the forces remain attractive, but in the electrostatic case the force must be repulsive to the one with the same charge and attractive to the one with the opposite charge. There is no way for the Coulomb force to mimic gravity with 3 or more objects, and the solar system has many more than 3 objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I understand that my question should have been phrased differently. 1) I agree that the proximity of Esrth

Comment: @ChristianSpeth it looks like you may have been cut off part way through your comment. I am not sure what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could drop something that was negatively charged and see whether it fell to Earth or flew away from Earth.

Gravity has only one sign of "gravitational charge" (aka mass), whereas the Coulomb force has two. It would be rapidly apparent whether oppositely charged things were affected by "gravity" differently.

If your argument is that the charge imbalance is so small that I couldn't do this simple experiment, then the effect will also be too small to affect gravity on large scales, since both gravity and Coulomb force depend on $r^{-2}$ in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

there are massive electrical forces between celestial bodies. every electron on earth repels every electron in the sun and attracts every proton in the sun (and these forces are orders of magnitude stronger than gravity). however, they all cancel out almost completely. this is because any local charge imbalance big enough to have a significant force would also be significant enough to act as a particle accelerator and throw the excess charged particles away from the celestial body.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree that the forces will cancel out if there is an equal number of positive and negative particles - evenly distributed - in the Universe. If this is not the case, there will be static elctricity. That was discoved by the ancient Greeks. Static will attract or repel other bodies depending on the charge. My question was not if such forces exist, but if it is possible to distinguish electrical forces from gravitational without direct contact. So, is it possible to determin if Pluto has an electrical potential differnet from Earth? Or a black hole?

Comment: the answer is that anything big is electrically neutral (where big means big enough that it is held together primarily by gravity). if such an object had an electrical charge, it would lose that charge since the repulsive forces would push away the charged particles.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments that solar wind will neutralize charges is valid. It's also true that an **attractive** force cannot exist between more than 2 bodies because they would have the same sign. A **repulsive** force could however exist with all planets having a slight positive charge. It would have to be a lot smaller than gravity to avoid tearing the planets apart, but that's fine.

**The supposed electrostatic force is directly calculable from precise measurements.**
Fundamentally this is because [mass affects both inertia and gravity equally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment), but charge affects only the force <sup>[1]</sup>.

The orbital speed is determined by inertia and [centripetal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) $F_c = \frac{m \cdot v^2}{r}$.

The [gravitational force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) is $F_g = G \cdot \frac{m \cdot M}{r^2}$.

Now suppose that there is an unknown force X acting in addition gravity:

$$F_c = F_g + X$$

I'll assume that we are on the larger body with mass $M$ (Earth) and observing a smaller body $m$ (Moon) that is on circular orbit:

$$X = \frac{m \cdot v^2}{r} - G \cdot \frac{m \cdot M}{r^2}$$

which can be rearranged to calculate the acceleration due to unknown force:

$$a_x = \frac{X}{m} = \frac{v^2}{r} - G \cdot\frac{M}{r^2}$$

The gravitational constant times our planet's mass $G \cdot M$ can be measured with a test mass. The distance $r$ to other body can be measured using parallax or radar. The orbital velocity $v$ can be determined from orbital period and $r$.

Plugging in the values for Earth and Moon we get 0.000019 m/s², which is two orders of magnitude smaller than the gravitational acceleration 0.00269 m/s² at Moon's distance. More precise analysis would be possible by solving the differential equations instead of assuming circular orbit.

---

<sub>[1] There is a small caveat on whether a planet-wide positive charge would disturb the Eötvos experiment and other fundamental experiments enough that we would end up with wrong basic formulas.</sub>

Comment: Your reply is very clear and understandable, but it assumes human presence not too far from the body in question. Several people thought I was thinking of Earth/Moon.